# Having trouble with box blocking element

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to click on a button "Groups" that has a dialog box in front of it. First I close the dialog box by clicking on 'OK' to close it, but sometimes selenium says it couldn't find the button "Groups" because something was blocking it. Other times **it will run fine**, I have no idea what's causing this issue to happen occasionally.

Here's my code:

```
upload_ok = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='dialogButton primary']")))
upload_ok.click()
groupstab = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Groups')]")))
groupstab.click()
```

This is the HTML:

```
<iframe id="tab_Admin" name="frame_Admin" data-bind="iframeSrc: link, attr: { id: 'tab_' + id + (index() || ''), name: 'frame_' + id + (index() || ''), class: ($parent.headless() === true ? 'headless ': '')  + (rightSliderUrl ? 'right-slider-space ' : '') + 'iframe-content' + ($parent.selectedTab() &amp;&amp; $parent.selectedTab().id === id &amp;&amp; $parent.selectedTab().index() === index() ? '' : ' iframe-content-unselected') }" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" src="/prism/admin?embed=ba1&amp;openTab=monitor" class="iframe-content">
    #document
        <!DOCTYPE html>

        <head></head>
    <body role="application" "="">
       <div class="main-content" id="mainContent">
        <div class="pageView adminView" style="">
            <div class="tabs>
                <button tab="0" class="selected">Users</button>
                <button tab="1">Groups</button>
                <button tab="2">Lifecycle Management</button>
                <button tab="3">Features</button>
                <button tab="4" class="">Databases</button>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    <div id="modalDialog_11" class="dialogBlocker show" style="height: 606px;">
            <div id="modalDialog_11Container" class="dialogBlockerCell adminDialog">
                <div class="modalDialog" tabindex="0" role="dialog">
                    <div class="dialogContent">
                        <h1>Success!</h1>
                        <div class="msg">
                            Your file 'users.csv' has been successfuly uploaded.<br>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            </div>
                        <footer style="margin-right: 20px;">
                            <button class="dialogButton primary" aria-label="OK" role="button" tabindex="1">OK
                            </button>
                        </footer>
                     </div>
                </div>
          </div>
    </body>
</iframe>
```

I don't know if there's something to do with the element class="dialogBlocker show" making the rest of the page to be greyed out behind the box or not.
Here's a screenshot of it:

[image: Box]

Anyone got ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: can you share the html before & after clicking on OK button

Comment: the HTML is exactly the same but without the last div <div id="modalDialog_11" class="dialogBlocker show" style="height: 606px;">.....</div>. I click on a button "upload users" inside the users tab and send the path to a <input> then the dialog box pops up saying it was sucessful

Comment: @Luiz : can you try my solution and let me know the result

Comment: ok. can you share the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: Did you switch to the `iframe` first?

Comment: @SiKing yes I did switch to the iframe.

Comment: @Sureshmani I'm not able to get the exactly error right now because I accidentally  deleted the log file, but it was something like this: " Element is not clickable at point (x, y) because another element obscures it" when trying to click on Groups.

Comment: You have to check which element is hindering the click() from the error message. I think @Christine answer would be suitable if it is due to alert window. You can also try to bring the element into view port before clicking on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the HTML you provided, this looks like a modal rather than an alert. You would just use the modal as if it were a normal HTML element. You might have to add a `wait` on the modal closing, so that `Groups` is not located before the modal is completely hidden.

I took your sample code and added an extra line to wait on `invisibility_of` for the modal dialog:

```
# wait to click OK
upload_ok = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='dialogButton primary']")))

# click OK
upload_ok.click()

# wait on modal to disappear
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'dialogBlocker')]")))

# wait on groups tab
groupstab = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Groups')]")))

# click groups tab
groupstab.click()
```

The `wait` on `groupstab` will almost always succeed, because the element is present underneath the modal, and still on the DOM. So it would make sense that you are receiving `ClickIntercepted` error, if the modal hasn't fully disappeared before clicking.

Another alternative, would be to attempt a Javascript click on `groupstab`, instead of `groupstab.click()`:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", groupstab)
```

Comment: My knowledge of HTML is very limited, I had no idea what modals were. Thank you for your answer, it seems to have worked, I went the the first option, I ran the code 3 times and didn't get an error! I have a question though, if I print your line it's showing "True" does this means it's because the element is invisible or because the modal element was found??

Comment: Which line are you printing? If you print the line under `# wait for the modal to disappear` then it would print true once the `EC` is met, meaning modal is hidden.

Comment: yes the line under # wait for the modal to disappear. Ok, I got it. Thank you!!!